# Flexible: Stretch Hips and Rotate Internal

Tags: exercise, stretching, flexibility, yoga, gymnastics

The following 2 Exercises will Rotate the Hips External. I am curious if anyone knows any stretches to Rotate the Hips Internal (opposite direction).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 90/90 stretch:

[image]

puts one hip in internal rotation and the other in external rotation.

I think dynamic stretching may be better.
This video shows some martial arts inspired dynamic external/internal hip rotation stretches: [VAHVA Fitness: Intelligent Hip Mobility Training](https://vahvafitness.com/intelligent-hip-mobility-training/).